# Scatter 2D coordinates from distance matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, coordinates, cluster-computing, distance

I'm looking for a solution that outputs a cluster of 2D points from an estimated distance matrix between some of them.
Thing is, the distance between those points are not exact (an approximation) and there aren't values for all pair combinations.

I'm looking for any type of solutions that creates approximate coordinates that respect at most the distances provided.

Comment: http://www.math.le.ac.uk/people/ag153/homepage/KmeansKmedoids/Kmeans_Kmedoids.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use [t-SNE](http://lvdmaaten.github.io/tsne/#implementations), an algorithm finding an embedding of potentially high-dimensional data into low-dimensional data based on the distances of the elements.

You will have to decide what to do with the missing distances, whether to set them at high values, or the mean distance, or something else.

Since t-SNE will preserve only local neighbourhoods, relations of distant clusters may be less accurate, but you'd have to see whether that is bad for your application.

---

**Update: example for t-SNE**

If you download the vanilla MATLAB implementation from the linked website and put that folder on the path, the following self-contained example should run.

```
%% Generate some random data
mu = [1 2];
Sigma = [1 0; 0 1];
R = chol(Sigma);
z1 = repmat(mu,100,1) + randn(100,2)*R;
mu = [5 1.5];
z2 = repmat(mu,100,1) + randn(100,2)*R;
mu = [3.5 6.5];
z3 = repmat(mu,100,1) + randn(100,2)*R;

%% Plot random data
figure(1);
clf
subplot(3, 1, 1)
scatter(z1(:,1), z1(:,2))
hold on
scatter(z2(:,1), z2(:,2))
scatter(z3(:,1), z3(:,2))
title('Original data')

%% Generate pw distance matrix and plot it
all_z = [z1; z2; z3];
% generate pw distance matrix
pwd = squareform(pdist(all_z));

subplot(3, 1, 2)
imagesc(pwd)
title('Distance matrix')

%% Perform tSNE
no_dims = 2;
perplexity = 150;
yd = tsne_d(pwd, [], no_dims, perplexity);
%% Plot results
subplot(3, 1, 3)
scatter(yd(1:100, 1), yd(1:100, 2))
hold on
scatter(yd((1:100) + 100, 1), yd((1:100) + 100, 2))
scatter(yd((1:100) + 200, 1), yd((1:100) + 200, 2))
title('tSNE embedding')
```

After sanitizing your distance matrix (i.e. assigning some value for the missing ones), you would start at `%% Perform tSNE`. `perplexity` is a parameter that should match approximately the number of points you expect in a cluster. In my example I chose 150, as I also want to consider neighbouring points a bit further away. The original paper has a good description of what the algorithm does.

Comment: Thanks. You mind explaining how to use it that way ? It's kinda hard for me since I have no maths background and never used that lib. Would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I do still have a couple of questions, if you don't mind: 
1. Is 'pwd' supposed to be the distance matrix with the zero'ed diagonal ?  
  
2. Is 'yd' supposed to be a matrix with the x-y coordinates of the final points to which the distance matrix was provided ?  
  
3. For example, if I have 3 points only and a distance 3*3 distance matrix, the perplexity should be 3 ?

Comment: 1. Yes 2. Yes 3. It depends on your data. I assume your points have some structure, i.e. you're looking at different groups, or there is a continuous variable. If you have two groups of 20 points, then perplexity = 25 might be a good choice. You can play with that parameter. Also, since the algorithm uses a random start point for its underlying optimisation, you'll get different results each time, and you can just pick the best one.

Comment: I'm don't have different groups, I just have 140 points to which I have the distance between them, pairwise. I just want, in the end, to have points that respect the distances previously set on the distance matrix.

I tested it using a 3*3, 4*4 and 5*5 distance matrix (with 3, 4, and 5 points, respectively) and I always get a final matrix with equivalent euclidian distances between all the points, i.e., it's like I get a symmetric   result set.

Comment: Try the default (I think it is 40). You can compare the performance by computing the pw distances of the output `yd` with your initial distance matrix.